How to make an attribute containing a url a clickable link in Geoserver
I have a PostGIS table with an attribute that contains a url, stored as plain text.  I'm rendering the table as a layer in Geoserver - how can I make this attribute into a clickable link?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Assuming you mean in a getFeatureInfo request then you need to look at the templating functionality and probably the tutorial.
You'll need a content.tfl file with something like:
<ul>
<#list features as feature>
  <li><a href="${feature.URL.value}">Point of interest, "${feature.NAME.value}"</a>: <br/>
  <img src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/popup_map/${feature.THUMBNAIL.value}"/>
  </li>
</#list>
</ul>

